# Multiple Billing forms in WooCommerce (one billing form per product)

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm building a travel site and I want to add this custom function to the WooCommerce checkout form: when a user adds 3 packages to his cart, I want to have 3 sets of Billing details (complete with Name, Address and so on) in the checkout form.

So the checkout form generates a billing details set for each product that's added to the cart.

Can this be done via a plugin or something, without custom work?

Comment: So you want the user to pay 3 times if you have 3 products? i don't think it's possible, since billing is linked with payment.

Comment: Not necessarily. I want to gather the info of 3 people if there are 3 travel package reservations in the Cart. So it can be one main billing address and 2 additional sets of information. But these have to be generated automatically based on the number of packages added to cart by the user.

So if the user adds 5 packages to Cart, I'll have the main Billing box and 4 other boxes to get the info of the other people traveling.

Comment: I am also trying the same thing but I have not found any solution. I am trying a plugin called allow multiple accounts for the same email for the same. But it is not working in the frontend. Please do share if you have found any solution for the same.

Comment: The original problem was separate billing details per item in the order, not multiple accounts for the same email?

Comment: Hey! Not found a solution, ended up not being able to do it all and changed strategy for the website. The issue was that one person should be able to make bookings for many other people, but those respective people would pay for the booking themselves. So there's no multiple accounts.